# How to find lines which do not match a list of patterns?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, regex-negation

I want to find all non-empty lines in a document which do not match a list of patterns. For example in the document snippet below I want a regular expression which matches line numbers 2, 4, 5, 6, 18, 19, 20 and 21.

I want to exclude lines similar to 8, 10, 12, 14, 16 and all empty lines.

The inverse pattern is `(?i)^.*02 December_|^\s*Python Proprietary|^\s*Python Regular Expression Specification|^.*page\s+\d+|^\s*$`. I want a pattern which matches all lines which do not match the aforementioned pattern.

```
 1:
 2:This module provides regular expression matching operations.
 3:
 4:Regular expressions use the backslash character ('\') to indicate special forms
 5:or to allow special characters to be used without invoking their special
 6:meaning.
 7:
 8:Python Regular Expression                                           02 December 1999 
 9:
10:                                                                 Python Proprietary 
11:
12:----------------------- Page 292-----------------------
13:
14:PYTHON RE SPECIFICATION Version 2.7 [Vol 9, Part Q]                     page 983 
15:
16:Python Regular Expression Specification 
17:
18:It is important to note that most regular expression operations are available as
19:module-level functions and RegexObject methods. The functions are shortcuts that
20:don’t require you to compile a regex object first, but miss some fine-tuning
21:parameters.
22:
```

P.S. -

1. I am using re.match().
2. The actual document doesn't have line-numbers at the beginning of each line. The line-numbers have been added in this snippet for ease of discussion.

Comment: What's wrong with just matching the lines you have, keeping track of the ones that don't match.

Comment: Is there a specific reason that you can't invert the match, and have your code return all lines except for the ones that match?

Comment: @PiëtDelport - I could but that would change the flow of the existing larger program. If I don't find a good answer here then that is exactly what I will be doing.

Comment: Can you explain the context, then? That would help formulate an answer.

Comment: @PiëtDelport - This is part of a document parser and the section of the parser I am modifying now follows the format - *match a pattern and if matched successfully do the respective action*.

Comment: IMHO,  Piët Delport's or PeterWood's comment are the way to go. If the code using it does not allow it, it is too tied to regexes. You should always allow (as an option) to use a function taking the line and returning a boolean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a negative look ahead:

#### REGEX

```
^(?i)(?!-+\s+Page\s+\d+-+|Python\s+Regular\s+Expression\s+\d{2}.+\d{4}|.+Python\s+Proprietary|PYTHON\s+RE SPECIFICATION\s+Version.+\s+page\s+\d+|Python\s+Regular\s+Expression\s+Specification).+$
```

#### DEMO

[Click to view](https://regex101.com/r/dK0iH5/1)

#### DESCRIPTION

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
^.*?Python Regular Expression.*?$(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|^.*?Python Proprietary.*?$(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|.*?Page \d+.*?$(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|^$(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|^.*?$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wL5kN6/1)

Result:

Matches 8 lines 2, 4, 5, 6, 18, 19, 20 and 21.

Explanation:

`^.*?Python Regular Expression.*?$(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` exclude lines 6, 16.
`^.*?Python Proprietary.*?$(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` exclude line 10.
`.*?Page \d+.*?$(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` exclude lines 12, 14.
`^$(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` exclude all empty lines.
`^.*?$` matches all other lines.